# How to update/convert mumeric TextBox value when changing value's unit using a ComboBox? Value normalization based on current unit?

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, mvvm, converters

I would like to have a converter system for my Xamarin and WPF project. I don't want to save any units in the database, so I want directly convert the textbox-values when user change the unit.

[image]

I made public a few Observable Collections like;

```
 public class AreaList : ObservableCollection<Unit>
    {
        public AreaList() : base()
        {
            Add(new Unit("mm²"));
            Add(new Unit("cm²"));
            Add(new Unit("dm²"));
            Add(new Unit("m²"));
        }
    }

 public class Unit
    {
        private string name;

        public Unit(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
    }
```

In the View i bind the collection to my combo box. I gave my TextBox the name of his binding property(Text="{Binding TxtBoxValue}" => x:Name="TxtBoxValue"). The ConvertUnitValueCommand set this name as a string in the view model to know which variable the converter function should use when the unit is changed.

View

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <c:AreaList x:Key="AreaListData" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<TextBox x:Name="TxtBoxValue"
         Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=TxtBoxValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</TextBox>

<ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          IsEditable="False"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Unit,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AreaListData}}">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
         <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ConvertUnitValueCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TxtBoxValue, Path=Name}" />
   </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers> 
</ComboBox>
```

ViewModel

```
private string ConvertControlName;

private void ConvertUnitValue(object obj)
{
    ConvertControlName = obj.ToString();
}

public Unit Unit
{
get => Get<Unit>();
set
{
     if (ConvertControlName != null)
     {
    FieldInfo variable = this.GetType().GetField(ConvertControlName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    //Get the Value from setted Binding Variable
    double oldValue = (double)variable.GetValue(this);

    //Convert the value
    if (oldValue > 0)
    {
         double newValue = Converts.ConvertUnitValue(Unit, value, oldValue);
         variable.SetValue(this, newValue);
    }

    Set(value);
    }
}
```

Maybe anyone can give me some inspiration to do it better.

Comment: If I am not wrong, you want to update the value in the textbox if the user changes the unit by using ComboBox. or I missed something?

Comment: Right! thats exactly what i want

Comment: You can encapsulate units into a enum-like class. Then create a dedicated custom control to edit units.

Comment: You always convert a value _from_ unit _to_ unit. Or how does your converter logic work, do you always convert to a base unit?

Comment: And why do you use reflection to access a field?

Comment: because i want to use that functionality for every textbox with a unit, multiple times in my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example normalizes the user input to the base unit *m²*:

**Unit.cs**

```
public class Unit
{
  public Unit(string name, decimal baseFactor)
  {
    this.Name = name;
    this.BaseFactor = baseFactor;
  }

  #region Overrides of Object

  /// <inheritdoc />
  public override string ToString() => this.Name;

  #endregion

  public string Name { get; set; }
  public decimal BaseFactor { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.Units = new List<Unit>()
    {
      new Unit("mm²", (decimal) (1 / Math.Pow(1000, 2))),
      new Unit("cm²", (decimal) (1 / Math.Pow(100, 2))),
      new Unit("dm²", (decimal) (1 / Math.Pow(10, 2))),
      new Unit("m²", 1)
    };
  }

  private void NormalizeValue()
  {
    this.NormalizedValue = this.UnitValue * this.SelectedUnit.BaseFactor;
  }

  private List<Unit> units;
  public List<Unit> Units
  {
    get => this.units;
    set
    {
      this.units = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private Unit selectedUnit;
  public Unit SelectedUnit
  {
    get => this.selectedUnit;
    set
    {
      this.selectedUnit = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();

      NormalizeValue();
    }
  }

  private decimal unitValue;
  public decimal UnitValue
  {
    get => this.unitValue;
    set
    {
      this.unitValue = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();

      NormalizeValue();
    }
  }

  private decimal normalizedValue;
  public decimal NormalizedValue
  {
    get => this.normalizedValue;
    set
    {
      this.normalizedValue = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**ManiWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DatContext>

  <StackPanel>

    <!-- Input -->
    <TextBox Text="{Binding UnitValue}" />
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Units}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUnit}" />

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NormalizedValue}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

### Reusable solution

A reusable solution would be to create a custom control, which derives from `TextBox` and encapsulates the normalization logic and the control design.

The following custom control `NormalizingNumericTextBox` extends `TextBox` and converts two way from non-normalized value to normalized and back.
It is basically a `TextBox` aligned with a `ComboBox` as `Unit` selector.
It may not be perfect, but it is ready to use and it just took me about 10 minutes to merge the previous answer into this custom control.

`NormalizingNumericTextBox` supports any type of unit describing a numeric value.
Just bind the `NormalizingNumericTextBox.Units` property to collection of any kind of `Unit` implementation e.g. weight, length, currency, etc.

Bind to `NormalizingNumericTextBox.NormalizedValue` to get/set the normalized value. Setting this property will convert the value to the current `NormalizingNumericTextBox.SelectedUnit`.
Bind to `NormalizingNumericTextBox.Text` for the raw input value.

Ensure that the default `Style` (see below) is added to the `ResourceDictionary` inside */Themes/Generic.xaml*. Customize this `Style` to customize appearance.

**ManiWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DatContext>

  <StackPanel>

    <!-- Input -->
      <NormalizingUnitTextBox NormalizedValue="{Binding NormalizedValue}" 
                              Units="{Binding Units}"
                              Width="180" />

    <!-- 
      Test to show/manipulate current normalized value of the view model.
      An entered normalized value will be converted back to the current NormalizingNumericTextBox.Unit -->
    <TextBox Background="Red" Text="{Binding NormalizedUnitValue}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Unit.cs**

```
public class Unit
{
  public Unit(string name, decimal baseFactor)
  {
    this.Name = name;
    this.BaseFactor = baseFactor;
  }

  #region Overrides of Object

  /// <inheritdoc />
  public override string ToString() => this.Name;

  #endregion

  public string Name { get; set; }
  public decimal BaseFactor { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.Units = new List<Unit>()
    {
      new Unit("m²", 1),
      new Unit("dm²", (decimal) (1/Math.Pow(10, 2))),
      new Unit("cm²", (decimal) (1/Math.Pow(100, 2))),
      new Unit("mm²", (decimal) (1/Math.Pow(1000, 2)))
    };
  }

  public List<Unit> Units { get; set; }

  private decimal normalizedValue;
  public decimal NormalizedValue
  {
    get => this.normalizedValue;
    set
    {
      this.normalizedValue = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**NormalizingNumericTextBox.cs**

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_UnitsItemsHost", Type = typeof(ItemsControl))]
public class NormalizingNumericTextBox : TextBox
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty UnitsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Units",
    typeof(IEnumerable<Unit>),
    typeof(NormalizingNumericTextBox),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable<Unit>), NormalizingNumericTextBox.OnUnitsChanged));

  public IEnumerable<Unit> Units
  {
    get => (IEnumerable<Unit>) GetValue(NormalizingNumericTextBox.UnitsProperty);
    set => SetValue(NormalizingNumericTextBox.UnitsProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedUnitProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SelectedUnit",
    typeof(Unit),
    typeof(NormalizingNumericTextBox),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
      default(Unit),
      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
      NormalizingNumericTextBox.OnSelectedUnitChanged));

  public Unit SelectedUnit
  {
    get => (Unit) GetValue(NormalizingNumericTextBox.SelectedUnitProperty);
    set => SetValue(NormalizingNumericTextBox.SelectedUnitProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalizedValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "NormalizedValue",
    typeof(decimal),
    typeof(NormalizingNumericTextBox),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
      default(decimal),
      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
      NormalizingNumericTextBox.OnNormalizedValueChanged));

  public decimal NormalizedValue
  {
    get => (decimal) GetValue(NormalizingNumericTextBox.NormalizedValueProperty);
    set => SetValue(NormalizingNumericTextBox.NormalizedValueProperty, value);
  }

  private ItemsControl PART_UnitsItemsHost { get; set; }
  private bool IsNormalizing { get; set; }

  static NormalizingNumericTextBox()
  {
    FrameworkElement.DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
      typeof(NormalizingNumericTextBox),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(NormalizingNumericTextBox)));
  }

  public NormalizingNumericTextBox()
  {
  }

  private static void OnNormalizedValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var _this = d as NormalizingNumericTextBox;
    _this.ConvertNormalizedValueToNumericText();
  }

  private static void OnSelectedUnitChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    (d as NormalizingNumericTextBox).NormalizeNumericText();
  }

  private static void OnUnitsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var _this = d as NormalizingNumericTextBox;
    _this.SelectedUnit = _this.Units.FirstOrDefault();
  }

  /// <inheritdoc />
  public override void OnApplyTemplate()
  {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    this.PART_UnitsItemsHost = GetTemplateChild("PART_UnitsItemsHost") as ItemsControl;

    if (this.PART_UnitsItemsHost == null)
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(this.PART_UnitsItemsHost)} not found in ControlTemplate");
    }

    this.PART_UnitsItemsHost.SetBinding(
      Selector.SelectedItemProperty,
      new Binding(nameof(this.SelectedUnit)) {Source = this});
    this.PART_UnitsItemsHost.SetBinding(
      ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty,
      new Binding(nameof(this.Units)) {Source = this});
    this.SelectedUnit = this.Units.FirstOrDefault();
  }

  #region Overrides of TextBoxBase

  /// <inheritdoc />
  protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnTextChanged(e);
    if (this.IsNormalizing)
    {
      return;
    }

    NormalizeNumericText();
  }

  /// <inheritdoc />
  protected override void OnTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
  {
    // Suppress non numeric characters
    if (!decimal.TryParse(e.Text, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out decimal _))
    {
      e.Handled = true;
      return;
    }

    base.OnTextInput(e);
  }

  #endregion Overrides of TextBoxBase

  private void NormalizeNumericText()
  {
    this.IsNormalizing = true;
    if (decimal.TryParse(this.Text, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out decimal numericValue))
    {
      this.NormalizedValue = numericValue * this.SelectedUnit.BaseFactor;
    }

    this.IsNormalizing = false;
  }

  private void ConvertNormalizedValueToNumericText()
  {
    this.IsNormalizing = true;
    decimal value = this.NormalizedValue / this.SelectedUnit.BaseFactor;
    this.Text = value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    this.IsNormalizing = false;
  }
}
```

**Generic.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary>

  <Style TargetType="NormalizingNumericTextBox">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:NormalizingNumericTextBox">
          <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0" />
              <ComboBox x:Name="PART_UnitsItemsHost" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </Grid>
          </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Very nice normalization functionality!!! But as i commented i search for a more general converting.

Comment: What do you mean by more general? I don't find anything about generic conversion in your question. Can please elaborate what you mean by more general?

Comment: I have more than one textbox with a unit-combobox. Every textbox with a unit combobox should use these functionality. Because of that i think must use the Generic conversation to find the textbox associated with the clicked combobox

Comment: I already provided the core of a reusable solution. Anyway, I've updated my answer to show how to encapsulate the conversion in to a nice convenient and customizable control - for free. Cause I am such a nice guy.

Comment: Heavy thanks!!! I appreciate that very much. I didn't expect that you build the whole functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have not much idea about your code impact but I would suggest you try below design which uses MVVM Pattern which removes tight coupling between UI and Backend.
I have separate out the things here

your XAML will have code like

```
    <TextBox x:Name="unitTextbox"
     Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    </TextBox>

    <ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
      IsEditable="False"
      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUnit}"
      ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableUnits}">
    </ComboBox>
```

Your ViewModel will be like

```
public class MainVm : Observable
{
    #region Private Fields
    private double _value;
    private ObservableCollection<Unit> _availableUnits;
    private Unit _selectedUnit;
    private Unit _previouslySelected;

    #endregion Private Fields

    #region Public Constructors

    public MainVm()
    {
        _availableUnits = new ObservableCollection<Unit>()
        {
          new Unit("mm²"),
          new Unit("cm²"),
          new Unit("dm²"),
          new Unit("m²")
        };
    }

    #endregion Public Constructors

    #region Public Properties

    public double Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_value != value)
            {
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public Unit SelectedUnit
    {
        get { return _selectedUnit; }
        set
        {

           _previouslySelected = _selectedUnit;
           _selectedUnit = value;
          // call to value conversion function
          // convert cm² to mm² or anything
           Value = UnitConvertor.Convert(_value, _previouslySelected.Name, _selectedUnit.Name);
           OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Unit> AvailableUnits => _availableUnits;

    #endregion Public Properties
}
```

My Observable class will be like

```
 public class Observable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Public Events

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion Public Events

    #region Protected Methods

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion Protected Methods
}
```

better to use an enum for units

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i already had that. I wanna use these convert Functionality for every textbox with a unit and look for a more general functionality